# underline two word in a Sentence with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, regex

It's my code but Only one word is underlined

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let firstword = 'web';
  let secondword = 'js';

  $(".field.ConditionsAccept>.caption:contains('" + secondword + "'):contains('" + firstword + "')").each(function() {
    var regex = new RegExp("(" + secondword + ")", 'g');
    var regex2 = new RegExp("(" + firstword + ")", 'g');
    $(this).html($(this).text().replace(regex, '<span class="word" style="text-decoration: underline">$1</span>'));
    $(this).html($(this).text().replace(regex2, '<span class="word2" style="text-decoration: underline">$1</span>'));
  });
});
```

```css
.ConditionsAccept { width: 500px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="field ConditionsAccept">
  <caption class="caption">Here is some web and js stuff</caption>
</table>
```

Comment: Please include the relevant html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: I come here for some good *C# tag*, and all I can see is munted *JavaScript*. Disappointed is an understatement. ***Pro Tip*** : *tag* your questions correctly, otherwise you will just get downvoted

Comment: I fixed the snippet for you. Next time please provide a [mcve] yourself

Answer (score 2):

Your second `$(this).text()` has stripped the first span from the content

It is also NOT a good idea to change the HTML twice. If the first word is `span` or `word` or `decoration` then the first span will be corrupted by the second change.

Safest solution is to replace all text before setting the HTML.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let firstword = 'web';
  let secondword = 'js';

  $(".field.ConditionsAccept>.caption:contains('" + secondword + "'):contains('" + firstword + "')").each(function() {
    const regex  = new RegExp("(" + secondword + ")", 'g');
    const regex2 = new RegExp("(" + firstword +  ")", 'g');
    let text = $(this).text()
    console.log(text)
    text = text
      .replace(regex,  '<span class="word"  style="text-decoration: underline">$1</span>')
      .replace(regex2, '<span class="word2" style="text-decoration: underline">$1</span>');
    $(this).html(text)
      
  });
});
```

```css
.ConditionsAccept { width: 500px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="field ConditionsAccept">
  <caption class="caption">Here is some web and js stuff</caption>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the function text() is being used to get the contents of the element. This gets the text, but the HTML is stripped. Therefore for the first use it does the replace of the word js OK but then the second use gets rid of the span element and so you are left with just the second use replacing the word (which is firstword in that regex) only.

This snippet uses the html() function instead of text() to make sure the span remains.

```html
<div class="field ConditionsAccept">
  <div class="caption">text0 js text web text1 js text3</div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    let firstword = 'web';
    let secondword = 'js';
    $(".field.ConditionsAccept>.caption:contains('" + secondword + "'):contains('" + firstword + "')").each(function() {
      var regex = new RegExp("(" + secondword + ")", 'g');
      var regex2 = new RegExp("(" + firstword + ")", 'g');
      $(this).html($(this).html().replace(regex, '<span class="word" style="text-decoration: underline">$1</span>'));
      $(this).html($(this).html().replace(regex2, '<span class="word2" style="text-decoration: underline">$1</span>'));
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Better is just replace both before assigning. Like I did. If there is a "word" in the replace, then the class is replaced inside the span

Comment: Could be better (depending on what the def of that is in this context) but I usually try not to change the question's code where it isn't necessary.

Comment: In your case, try `let firstword = 'word';` or `text` or `decoration`

Answer (score 0):

I made a sample using your code and meet the sample issue as you said. How I solved it is to change code as below:

```
            $(this).html($(this).html().replace(regex, '<span class="word" style="text-decoration: underline">$1</span>'));
            $(this).html($(this).html().replace(regex2, '<span class="word2" style="text-decoration: underline">$1</span>'));
```

It works for me. You can have a try.