# Turn specific words in array in a Tag with that word (No jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can you make it so that with the help of a JavaScript script you can pick out a word from a text that is in a P element with a class and turn it into a tag. For example I have such a text:

```html
<p class="codeText">Hello World, this Text say Hello World</p>
```

and a array in javascript:

```
const words = ["Hello", "World", "Text"];
```

How could I do that in the scheme:

> If Word from Class codeText has words from the array then turn the word in `<b>Word</b>`

I know it's a bit complicated, if you have any questions then please comment

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find words from a list and wrap each in a span?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45122488/find-words-from-a-list-and-wrap-each-in-a-span)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same basic concept as the one I answered a few hours ago

[underline two word in a Sentence with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68902658/underline-two-word-in-a-sentence-with-jquery)

but you want vanilla JS

Regexp

```js
const words = ["Hello", "World", "Text"];
const codeText = document.querySelector(".codeText");
let text = codeText.textContent
words.forEach(word => text = text.replace(new RegExp(`(${word})`,"g"),"<b>$1</b>"))
codeText.innerHTML = text
```

```html
<p class="codeText">Hello World, this Text say Hello World</p>
```

I do NOT recommend you replace the innerHTML in a loop - see the span class is mangled

```js
const words = ["Hello", "World", "Text"];
const codeText = document.querySelector(".codeText");
words.forEach(word => codeText.innerHTML = codeText.innerHTML.replaceAll(word,`<b>${word}</b>`))
```

```css
.Text { color: red; }
```

```html
<p class="codeText">Hello World, this <span class="Text">Text</span> say Hello World</p>
```

ReplaceAll

```js
const words = ["Hello", "World", "Text"];
const codeText = document.querySelector(".codeText");
let text = codeText.textContent;
words.forEach(word => text = text.replaceAll(word,`<b>${word}</b>`))
codeText.innerHTML = text;
```

```css
.Text { color: red; }
```

```html
<p class="codeText">Hello World, this <span class="Text">Text</span> say Hello World</p>
```

Comment: There are many duplicates to this question on SO...

Comment: In this case it was faster to write the answer than to find the dupe not using jQuery ;)

Comment: @JustChillinInDaHood See second example for why not use replaceAll using innerHTML

Comment: And see 3rd example if you only have text and want to use replaceAll

Comment: @mplungjan I understand what you're saying about replacing `.innerHTML` but in this case (`<span class="Text">Text</span>` inside the `p` with CSS `.Text {color: red}`) `.textContent` is no better. The class isn't "mangled" it is complely removed, the final result (visualy) is excatly the same. If the question would have mention such case `.textContent` nor `.innerHTML` would have been valid options.

Answer (score 0):

For Each `p.codeText` you need to replace every word in `words` by the same word in a `<b>`. Something like that

```js
const words = ["Hello", "World", "Text"];
document.querySelectorAll('.codeText').forEach(p => {
  words.forEach(word => {
    p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.replaceAll(word, `<b>${word}</b>`);
  });
});
```

```html
<p class="codeText">Hello World, this Text say Hello World</p>
```

Comment: This will fail if you have `span class="codeText">Hello</span>` in the `p`

Comment: Hi Cedric thank you so much for your effort! Unfortunately for you @mplungjan was faster that you, but you get a +1 cause it's also a good way! ;)

Comment: @mplungjan i wasn't thinking about using something other that `p` but you're right