# Adding style to specific word just replaces the word

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this textarea with code to replace the word with a tag:

```css
.code {
            width: 99%;
            padding: 1em 0 1em 10px;
            background: #000;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 10px;
            border-left: 5px solid #00d5ff;
            border-top: none;
            border-bottom: none;
            border-right: none;
            white-space: pre;
            overflow: scroll;
        }
```

```html
<textarea class="code" readonly autocomplete="off">
.toggleMenuButton .barTwo {
    opacity: 0;
}</textarea>
```

I also made a script to get the height of the textarea but i didn't include it to this question because it would be too long

Then i made a script to replace the words with `b-tags` with inline styles that are in a array. But after i made i realized that it's a textarea and instead of styling the word it just replaced the word.

Here's the code:

```js
const words = [".toggleMenuButton"]

document.querySelectorAll('.code').forEach(p => {
                words.forEach(word => {
                    p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.replaceAll(word, `<label style="color: #e2e2e2;">${word}</label>`);
                });
            });
```

```css
.code {
            width: 99%;
            padding: 1em 0 1em 10px;
            background: #000;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 10px;
            border-left: 5px solid #00d5ff;
            border-top: none;
            border-bottom: none;
            border-right: none;
            white-space: pre;
            overflow: scroll;
        }
```

```html
<textarea class="code" readonly autocomplete="off">
.toggleMenuButton .barTwo {
    opacity: 0;
}</textarea>
```

Here is another example if you do the same in a p-tag. It works:

```js
const words = [".toggleMenuButton"]

document.querySelectorAll('.code').forEach(p => {
                words.forEach(word => {
                    p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.replaceAll(word, `<label style="color: #e2e2e2;">${word}</label>`);
                });
            });
```

```html
<p class="code">.toggleMenuButton is a class and is called .toggleMenuButton</p>
```

How could i fix this problem? Do you guys have an idea?

Comment: That is because `<textarea></textarea>` can contain only text, if you type HTML code into it, it will be treated as plain text.

Comment: "_it's a textarea_" is the answer, only plain text is permitted content in a [textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea).

Comment: Here is another reason why not replace HTML in a loop: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68907360/turn-specific-words-in-array-in-a-tag-with-that-word-no-jquery

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I embed HTML formatting inside of a <textarea> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580247/can-i-embed-html-formatting-inside-of-a-textarea-tag)

Comment: By the way, may I ask you why you are using a read-only text area instead of a simple div?

Comment: @secan beacuse HTML-Code can't be shown in a div. In a textarea it can. If i could do it in a simple div than I wouldn't even ask this question

Comment: @secan - Doh! I missed it was *read only*. :-)

Comment: @JustChillinInDaHood then I think you need something a little bit more complex than the JavScript function you have; You might want to use [`DOMParser()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to recognize and manipulate the tags inside your div

Comment: @secan solved it by replacing `<` with `&lt;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it's a `textarea`, its contents are not rendered as HTML.

Instead, use a `div` or similar (I originally said a [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable) `div` or similar, but I'd missed that your `textarea` was read-only):

```js
const words = [".toggleMenuButton"]

document.querySelectorAll('.code').forEach(p => {
  words.forEach(word => {
    p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.replaceAll(word, `<label style="color: lightgreen;">${word}</label>`);
  });
});
```

```css
.code {
  width: 99%;
  padding: 1em 0 1em 10px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 10px;
  border-left: 5px solid #00d5ff;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-right: none;
  white-space: pre;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="code" readonly autocomplete="off">
  .toggleMenuButton .barTwo { opacity: 0; }
</div>
```

*(In that example, I've changed the color to light green to make it stand out more.)*

Here's an example with HTML:

```js
const html = `<p>Testing <strong>one<\/strong> two three`;

const code = document.querySelector('.code');
code.textContent = html;

const encoderDiv = document.createElement("div");
function encodeHTML(str) {
    encoderDiv.textContent = str;
    return encoderDiv.innerHTML;
}
/* If you need it:
function decodeHTML(html) {
    const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/html");
    return doc.body.textContent;
}
*/

const words = [".toggleMenuButton", "<strong>", "<\/strong>"];
for (const element of document.querySelectorAll('.code')) {
    for (const word of words) {
        const encoded = encodeHTML(word);
        element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replaceAll(encoded, `<label style="color: lightgreen;">${encoded}</label>`);
    }
}
```

```css
.code {
  width: 99%;
  padding: 1em 0 1em 10px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 10px;
  border-left: 5px solid #00d5ff;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-right: none;
  white-space: pre;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="code" readonly autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi TJ! Unfortunately i will also use HTML-Code and that doesn't work with HTML-Code :(

Comment: @JustChillinInDaHood - If you mean you "can't" put HTML inside a div, sure you can -- you just have to encode the `<` and `&` characters (best to also encode `>`, though it may not be necessary).

Comment: @JustChillinInDaHood - I've added an HTML example.

Comment: Hi TJ! Thanks i made it so that the `<` are turned into `&lt;` and it works like a charm!

Comment: @JustChillinInDaHood - Don't forget `&` => `&amp;` (and for best results, `>` => `&gt;`). Glad that helped!